# How to Overwrite (Nested) Jekyll Variables?

Tags: variables, jekyll, liquid

I have a collection of *components* in my site, they are populated with contents that are being specified by variables in a .yml file.

*site.components/button.html*

```
---
title: Button
---
{% assign yml = 'sample' %}
<a href="#">{{ site.data.[yml].button }}</a>
```

*data/sample.yml*

```
#variables
button: Click Me
```

When I open the url */button.html* the variable works nicely:

```
#Page Output
<html>
  <a href="#">Click Me</a>
</html>
```

---

**Q:** Is there any way to overwrite the variable when the component is used in a page? eg:

```
---
title: A Sample Page 
---
{% assign yml = 'content'%}
{{ site.components | where:"title" : "Button" }}
```

*data/content.yml*

```
#variables
button: Join Now
```

*/sample-page.html*

```
#Page Output
<html>
  <a href="#">Join Now</a>
</html>
```

Note the components are not includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is NO.

When you do a `{{ site.components | where:"title" : "Button" }}` you get an array of Jekyll Documents that match the title. Those documents are already liquid parsed. You cannot instruct jekyll to parse them again.

The only way is to use includes and pass them variables.

*_includes/button.html*

```
<a href="#">{{ site.data.[include.text].button }}</a>
```

*_components/button.html*

```
---
title: Button
---
{% include button.html text='sample' %}
```

*sample-page.html*

```
---
title: A Sample Page
---
{% include button.html text='content' %}
```